# Layout Inspector doesn't work with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, layout-inspector

Layout Inspector doesn't work with Jetpack Compose and the hint is

**Compose inspection unavailable. Could not determine the version of the androidx.compose.ui:ui artifact. Was the version file excluded?**

[image: Layout Inspection]

I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: did it stop working after you added a dependency? Also the known first step: have you tried clearing cache and restarting AS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have excluded the version file as the warning says. Version file is contained under META-INF folder. It should be something like META-INF/*.version. If you have something like below try removing it.

```
packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += "META-INF/*.version"
            excludes += "META-INF/**"               
        }
    }
```

Refer to [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244120504#comment16) for more details.